# Can I create a empty branch on a remote using git? Is there Anyway I can atleast create a local empty branch and push it to remote?

Tags: git, version-control

[Is it possible in git to create a new, empty remote branch without pushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574266/is-it-possible-in-git-to-create-a-new-empty-remote-branch-without-pushing) --- This doesn't work for me because even if I am using --orphan command, I can't push it to a remote.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a new *local* branch (created with `--orphan`), you would still need to push it after having created it:

```
git -c "push.default=current" push -u origin newBranch
```

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".
For the `-c` option, see "[Is they a way to set `push.default` to `current` only for the current push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31649345/6309)".

Comment: The problem is not with the Push.The problem is with creating "empty" branch , without any content on a remote repository which has many branches. Tried using this : git commit –allow-empty -m “Empty Branch” But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SnigdhaGayatri well, an orphan branch created locally, and then push will create an empty branch on the remote repo.

Comment: @SnigdhaGayatri what is the exact command you have typed, and the exact error message you got?

Comment: git checkout --orphan newBranch ; git push origin newBranch ---> "src refspec newBranch does not match any. "

Comment: @SnigdhaGayatri try: `git -c "push.default=current" push -u origin newBranch`. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The answer didn't actually work for me, so I just committed the .gitignore file and then just did a normal push `git push --set-upstream origin newBranch` and it did work.