# How to create a new, empty remote branch from a specific remote branch without pushing local code?

Tags: git, github

I see a relevant answer for creating an empty remote branch from master on this: [Is it possible in git to create a new, empty remote branch without pushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574266/is-it-possible-in-git-to-create-a-new-empty-remote-branch-without-pushing), using the following command:

`git push origin origin:refs/heads/new_feature_name`

But I need to create this new remote branch from a specific branch, other than master, without pushing code from local branch. How do I achieve that?

Comment: There's no such thing as an *empty* branch, in Git. That's not particularly important to your problem but if you think of this as "create an empty branch" you'll eventually get stuck because there isn't any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

First commit your local changes.
Suppose if you want to create a branch from branch A which is not a master branch.
Then go to that branch by using below command

**git checkout A**

Then execute below commands.

1. **git checkout -b branch_name**
2. **git push origin branch_name**

The above commands create local and remote branches.